# Is there a keyboard shortcut to paste quoted text in new Gmail composing editor?

Tags: gmail

Is there a keyboard shortcut to paste as quoted text?

Now the quoting button is hidden in the "Formatting" bar so figured a keyboard shortcut would be handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, after posting the bounty I found it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: Where have you found the answer?

Comment: Tool tip of the quoting button. Wasn't there before but seems like they have since added it.

Comment: For more cool keyboard shortcuts, see http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/03/new-gmail-shortcuts-for-composing.html

Comment: @Alex didn't know about the `kbd` tag. Thanks!

Comment: Not that it changes much, but it is also possible to do ctrl+shift+v+9 (edit: seems to actually work for single line quotes.. other wise it quotes "twice")